# How to stop IOS Alarm notification

Tags: ios

My app is a security app means.It runs in Guided mode only.User suppose not to do any thing when app is running in Guided mode.So I don't want that even Alarm notification POP in when my app is running in guided mode.I want to  gradually kill that notification.I did find any way where I notified for Alarm notification and kill that silently.

Comment: You should probably look at the Apple Configurator and single app mode rather than guided access

Comment: That is for MDM .But I don't want that .

Comment: You can use apple Configurator without an MDM and if these are dedicated devices then I would suggest that this is a good approach. If you can't dedicate the device then I don't think there is a solution

Comment: Apple added that support in IOS 9 .